# How do i read a text file INCLUDING empty lines in batch?

Tags: batch-file, text

I want to make it so that the empty lines are also outputted. For eg, this is my example.txt file.

```
Hello 

This is a text file. Hello World!
```

And my code to run it is,

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cd%\example.txt) DO ( 
echo. %%a
)
```

But it doesnt show the empty lines and instead shows it like

```
Hello
This is a text file. Hello World!
```

How do I make it so it shows the empty line too? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `Type `[command](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html)

Comment: hey so i found that instead of typing "echo. %%a" if i typed only "%%a" It treats all the text in the file as commands. Which is useful! Either way, thanks You can see my code at [link]github.com/mrc2rules/LimitLess and maybe suggest something

Answer (score 3):

FOR /F ignores empty lines, but you can use findstr to prefix each line with a line number, then there aren't empty lines anymore.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%~dp0\example.txt"') DO (
   set "line=%%L"
   set "line=!line:*:=!" & rem Remove all characters to the first colon
   echo(!line!
)
```

The problem with delayed expansion is that it destroys all `!` and `^` characters from your file.

Therefore, you could toggle the mode.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%~dp0\example.txt"') DO (
   set "line=%%L"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "line=!line:*:=!" & rem Remove all characters to the first colon
   echo(!line!
   endlocal
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x IN ("TYPE example.txt") DO (
  %%x
)
```

Comment: How does writing the string `TYPE example.txt` to the screen answer the question?

Comment: I'm sorry currently i have no explanation, but It's work on my case. show all the line within text file, incude blank line.

Comment: There is no chance it does what you say. It might actually show the content of the file when the quoting is corrected, but empty lines will definitively not show.